# How to make hard drive space in Linux?

Tags: server, disk-usage

I have run out of space on my server and am looking to cut some unused data out. Where should I look for this?
When running  `du -sh *` in the base directory some directories popped out.

```
3.9G    var
4.5G    usr
3.5G    lib
```

Seeing as I have 15GB space on my server these are the culprits.

Within `/var/cache/apt` there is a huge directory `2.1G archives` is that normal?

Within `/usr` there is also a rather large directory `2.1G  src` with folder names similar to `linux-headers-3.13.0-100` repeated many times.

Within `/lib` there is yet another `3.3G    modules` with folder names like `3.13.0-103-generic` repeated many times.

Are any of these unexpectedly large? Any general tips for cutting space on an ubuntu server?

Comment: Try apt-get autoremove

Comment: Please clarify your question so it can be found easier ;)

Comment: Hopefully the edit has made my question easier to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package updates leave older software packages including the kernel versions.

For cleaning those packages do :

```
apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Dark Magiks. 94% ->57%. That was amazing.

Comment: XD Glad to see that

Comment: @JasonBasanese `# apt-get autoclean` probably will free some more disk space.

Comment: @UTF-8 Does that avoid the Kernel ?

Comment: @userdepth No, it doesn't. Why would it? Or, better still: Why should it?

Comment: You can also run `sudo purge-old-kernels` (from `byobu` package) to remove old kernels, letting only the current and previous kernel.

Comment: @UTF-8 Some recommend having more than one Kernel version. I have had any crash so I do worry much but in Servers this can be a different case

Comment: @userdepth Ah, but `autoclean` doesn't remove any packages. It only cleans aptitude's cache.

Comment: @UTF-8 That's nice